# Read info from text file in CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a text file `text1.txt` that contains:

```
username
password
```

How can I read these parameters from `text1.txt` into my `.cgi` script?

I use this code :

```
f = open('text1.txt', "r") 
 user = f.readline() 
 pass = f.readline() 
$MAIN_AUTH = 'user':'pass' ;
```

This does not work.

If I directly insert user and pass it works:

```
$MAIN_AUTH = 'username:password' ;
```

But when read from the text file it does not work.

Comment: What is is arbitrary code? Have you checked what `open` does?  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html You need http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: It seems like python inspite of sigil at last var. If you are interested in python's solution, you probably should remove perl tag or provide perl not working example.

Comment: Probably it doesn't work because the code you show is neither valid Python nor valid Perl. Please tell which language you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will have linefeeds at the end of your two variables if you use `readline()`.

So, if it's Python, you will need to call `rstrip()` and if Perl, you will need `chomp()`.

Answer (score 0):

The overall logic you use is almost ok, but the syntax is not and there are some details. Because you said the line `$MAIN_AUTH = 'username:password';` works, I assume you have Perl code. Starting variables with a `$` is not allowed in Python (afaik).

1. ***Always*** add `use strict; use warnings 'all';` at the top of your Perl scripts. It will inform you about most common errors in your script.
2. Give the full path to your input file because you cannot be sure about the current directory when your cgi script is run by Apache (or whomever), and the script will expect it relative to that working directory if you don't state an absolute path.
3. Check the return code of `open` to see whether it worked.
4. When reading a line from a file, the line still has the newline character at its end, so remove that for further processing by applying `chomp` to every line.

Altogether I end up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open( my $fh, '<', '/path/to/text1.txt' ) or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
my ($user, $pass) = (<$fh>, <$fh>);  # read first two lines
chomp($user, $pass);                 # strip off trailing "\n" from both
close($fh);

my $MAIN_AUTH = "$user:$pass";

print "'$MAIN_AUTH'\n";
```

Output:

```
'username:password'
```

Comment: I copy this code to a new.cgi and set 755 permission to it but show error 500

Comment: Do you have apache? Then look into it's logfile (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` ??) and see what apache says.

Comment: Then either you look into the wrong logfile or your apache is configured to write it a) _not_ or b) _elsewhere._  When you call that script manually (`cd cgi-bin-directory; ./new.cgi`), what does it say then?

Comment: Show me below error     server cgi-bin]$ ./new.cgi
Cannot open file: No such file or directory

Comment: Then you gave the wrong path to your `text1.txt`. What's the full path to `text1.txt`? Of course you must change `/path/to/text1.txt` in my example to the actual path.

Comment: My text1.txt is in cgi-bin folder so i use :`open( my $fh, '<', 'text1.txt' ) or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";`

Comment: Then your file isn't there and I'm out. Figure out where your `text1.txt` file is and give that very path to the `open()` call. I cannot see your directory structure and cannot help any further. Try `find / -name new.cgi 2>/dev/null` to locate your file and use that result.

Comment: how can i use URL for this text1.txt file?   i find location but not work i want to use URL to read it.

Comment: I dont know  what is problem show me `Software error:

Cannot open file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I test code in this website : `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php` code : `#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
open( my $fh, '<', "http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/test.txt" ) or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
my ($user, $pass) = (<$fh>, <$fh>);  # read first two lines
chomp($user, $pass);    # strip off trailing "\n" from both
close($fh);
my $MAIN_AUTH = "$user:$pass";
print "'$MAIN_AUTH'\n";` but show `Cannot open file: No such file or directory

Comment: Then do as Alexandr suggested in the [very first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164622/read-info-from-text-file-in-cgi/38170374?noredirect=1#comment63761799_38164622) on your question! **`open()` is for local files** and the solution I proposed works like a charm: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMajZSQnFfX2Z5X1U . To fetch a file from some URL you need [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) instead.